# How to make layout for dgrid with dijit/Toolbar?

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I place dgrid table into widget, but grid overlapped my toolbar. How to fix broken layout?

Here current layout for my custom widget:

```
<div data-dojo-type="desktop/users/UsersWidget">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/LayoutContainer">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Toolbar" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
        <!-- Here buttons, separators, etc -->
        </div>

        <div data-dojo-type="desktop/grids/UsersGrid" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, CSS:

```
html, body, .layout-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

index.html

```
<body class="Claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/LayoutContainer" class="layout-container" id="layoutContainer">
        <div data-dojo-type="desktop/menus/MainMenu" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My widget initialized when user select one of main menu items and added as child of layoutContainer widget.

Comment: Please post you CSS too.

Comment: Added. All widget have 100% height, but dgrid placed as absolute div and overlapped toolbar, but not main menu. I copy layout, but it's not work (and I wrote to SO after 2 hour search)

Comment: this is usually a sizing issue. Having things to 100% is not always enough as EVERY single dom node must be 100% all along the line, from the ```html``` to  the ```LayoutContainer```. For the sake of testing can you give a size in ```px``` to all your ```LayoutContainer``` ?